# Access Cosmos Db JSON data using C# MVC

Tags: c#, json, nested, azure-cosmosdb, subitem

I am trying to display Cosmos db JSON Subitems using c# MVC Web application.
But I am getting an error:

> Could not cast or convert from System.DateTime to WebApplication1.Models.Entry.

**JSON:**

```
 "DataTypeId": 1,
"IPaddress": "192.168.2.177",
"id": "d1b81653-b7a5-4d79-85ea-79c01f43f747",
"PhoneNo": "0417518324",
"LastContact": {
    "EnvLog": "2019-09-07T19:41:08",
    "Ping": "2020-01-09T12:10:09",
    "SpdLog": "2019-09-07T19:41:08"
},
"SpeedLog": true,
"DeviceModelId": 2,
"DisconnectEvents": 9,
```

**Model:**

```
    public class DeviceMap
{

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "id")]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "IPaddress")]
    public string IPaddress { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "SpeedLog")]
    public bool SpeedLog { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "LastContact")]
    public Entry LastContact { get; set; }
}

 public class Entry

{

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "EnvLog")]
    public DateTime EnvLogtime { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "Ping")]
    public DateTime Ping { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "SpdLog")]
    public DateTime SpdLog { get; set; }
}
}
```

**Controller:**

```
public class DeviceMapController : Controller
{
    [ActionName("Index")]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Map1Async()
    {
        string empty = "Unknown";

        var items = await DocumentDBRepository<DeviceMap>.GetMap1Async(d => d.Id != null, d => d.Lat != empty);
        if (Convert.ToInt32(User.GroupId()) != 200) 
            {
                items = items.Where(d => d.GroupId == Convert.ToInt32(User.GroupId()));

        }

        return View(items);

    }
}
```

**View:**

```
             @foreach (var item in Model)
                    {


                        if ((@item.IPaddress == "192.168.2.14") || (@item.IPaddress == "192.168.2.13") || (@item.IPaddress == "192.168.2.15") || (@item.IPaddress == "192.168.2.16")) { }
                        else
                        {

                            //SideId string
                            string siteId = null;
                            string newsiteId = null;
                            if (item.IPaddress != "0")
                            {

                                int index = item.IPaddress.IndexOf('.') + 1;
                                int space = item.IPaddress.IndexOf('.', index + 1);
                                int space2 = item.IPaddress.IndexOf('.', space + 1);
                                int end = item.IPaddress.Length;
                                if (index > 0) { siteId = item.IPaddress.Substring(space + 1, end - space - 1); newsiteId = siteId.Replace('.', '-'); }
                            }
                           //  string Cutoff =Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.LastContact.Ping).ToString();
                         // DateTime day = DateTime.Parse(Cutoff.Value,"dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);

                          DateTime myday =Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.LastContact.Ping);
                            DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
                            DateTime yesterday = now.AddDays(-7);
                            DateTime d;
                       //  DateTime.TryParseExact(myday,@"dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.AssumeUniversal,out d);


                          // if (Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.LastContact.Ping) != null) { d = DateTime.Parse(myday, "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture); } else { myday = DateTime.ParseExact("08/04/2000 14:00:02", "dd/MM/yyyy HH: mm:ss", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture); }

                            string a = @item.Name;



                            <tr>

                                <td>

                                    @if (a.Length > 50) { a = a.Substring(0, 50); }



                                        @if (item.GroupId != 82)
                                        {

                                            if (myday <= DateTime.Now.AddDays(-7))
                                            {<h4>@myday</h4>
                                                    <img src="/Content/Images/trafficlight-red2.png" width="20" height="20"><a href="@Url.Action("DevicePage", "Device", new { item.DeviceId })"><h6>@a..</h6></a>
                                            }
                                            else
                                            {<img src="/Content/Images/trafficlight-green1.png" width="20" height="20"><a href="@Url.Action("DevicePage", "Device", new { item.DeviceId })"><h6>@a..</h6></a>
                                            }
                                        }


                                        else
                                        {


                                            if (myday <= DateTime.Now.AddDays(-7))
                                            {
                                                <img src="/Content/Images/trafficlight-red2.png" width="20" height="20"><a href="@Url.Action("Form", "TARP", new { item.DeviceId })"><h6>@a..</h6></a>
                                            }
                                            else
                                            {<img src="/Content/Images/trafficlight-green1.png" width="20" height="20"><a href="@Url.Action("Form", "TARP", new { item.DeviceId })"><h6>@a..</h6></a>

                                            }

                                        }

                                        @if (item.IPaddress != "0")
                                        {<p>Site Id: @newsiteId;</p>}
                                    @if (item.LastPing != null)
                                    {
                                        <p>
                                            Last Contact: @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.LastContact.Ping), @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.BatVoltage)V

                                        </p>}
```

I want to disply Ping date and time. Please, help.
Also if you have resources on how to call different styled JSON data please provide link for reference.
Thank you.

Comment: In the JSON, `LastContact` is a single `Entry` object. But in your model `LastContact` is of type `Dictionary<string, Entry>`. What should it be?

Comment: LastContact is single entry object. but not sure how to call it

Comment: change the objects in your `Entry` class to `DateTime` and change `Dictionary<string, Entry>` to just `Entry`.

Comment: Can you please explain more or provide informative link @Jawad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class DeviceMap
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "id")]
    public string Id { get; set; } // Suggestion: Change this to 'Guid' instead of string

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "IPaddress")]
    public string IPaddress { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "SpeedLog")]
    public bool SpeedLog { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "LastContact")]
    public Entry LastContact { get; set; }
}

public class Entry

{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "EnvLog")]
    public DateTime EnvLogtime { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "Ping")]
    public DateTime Ping { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "SpdLog")]
    public DateTime SpdLog { get; set; }
}
```

Your LastContact will deserialize correctly if you select `DateTime` as the type of each variable in `Entry`.

**Testing**

I used your json and converted it to DeviceMap object to test it and make sure that above works.

```
{
  "DataTypeId": 1,
  "IPaddress": "192.168.2.177",
  "id": "d1b81653-b7a5-4d79-85ea-79c01f43f747",
  "PhoneNo": "0417518324",
  "LastContact": {
    "EnvLog": "2019-09-07T19:41:08",
    "Ping": "2020-01-09T12:10:09",
    "SpdLog": "2019-09-07T19:41:08"
  },
  "SpeedLog": true,
  "DeviceModelId": 2,
  "DisconnectEvents": 9
}
```

and used the following in my main to deserialize it to make sure it works correctly.

```
DeviceMap map = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DeviceMap>(json);
```

[image: Screenshot of Data in map.]

It is definitely better to define the types in class so that at time of deserialization, you wont have to parse it to the types they should be. Deserializer should take care of that for you and convert your strings to type of your class if it is convertible, like, automatically converting string to `Guid` or `DateTime`.

Comment: after adding Deserialization code, I am getting error "CS0103 C# The name 'json' does not exist in the current context" I have aalso added Newtonsoft.Json library. @Jawad

Comment: json is a string that holds the content of your json data. Thats my test variable.

Comment: @Ana, were you able to sort this out?

Comment: No still struggling with it. @Jawad Can you please explain more

Comment: @Ana Have you updated the classes like mentioned here? How are you deserializing the json

Comment: I know it sounds dumb.. I have updated classes but just whole deserializing part is confusing as I am not using JSON straight way its through cosmos db(azure) @Jawad

Comment: chat: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205718/discussion-between-jawad-and-ana

Comment: I am able to display data on View page now. But for my project I need to compare DATE with yesterday, as updated code. but I am getting error:   Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error CS0029 Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Web.Mvc.MvcHtmlString' to 'System.DateTime' 
 can anybody help?

Comment: @Ana Please start a new question on that. Do mark the post answered if it help answer the original post